# is there a fast way to find probabilities like this $\mathbb{P}_0(T_0 = 2)$?

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, stopping-times

let $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ be a homogeneous Markov chain with state space $S = \{0,1,2\}$ and transition matrix $P$ :

$$P = \begin{pmatrix}0.1 & 0.3 & 0.6 \\
0.5 & 0.2 & 0.3 \\
0.4 & 0.4 & 0.2 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

let $T_0 = \min \{n \geq 1\, | \, X_n = 0\}$ and $\mathbb{P}_0(\cdot) = \mathbb{P}(\cdot|X_0 = 0) $

My attempt :

$$\begin{align}\mathbb{P}_0(T_0 = 2) &= \mathbb{P}(T_0 = 2|X_0 = 0) = \mathbb{P}(X_2 = 0, X_1 \neq 0|X_0 = 0) \\
& = \sum_{k = 1,2}\mathbb{P}(X_2 = 0, X_1 = k|X_0 = 0) \\ &=  \sum_{k = 1,2}\mathbb{P}(X_2 = 0 | X_1 = k, X_0 = 0)\mathbb{P}(X_1 = k | X_0 = 0) \\ & = \sum_{k = 1,2}\mathbb{P}(X_2 = 0 | X_1 = k)\mathbb{P}(X_1 = k | X_0 = 0) \\ & = 0.3\cdot0.5 + 0.6 \cdot 0.4 = 0.39 \end{align}$$

is there some faster way to do this ? learning about shortcuts will help a lot with problems where the transition matrices are very big.

Comment: In general, no. Given the stationary distribution $\pi$, we have $\mathbb E[T_i] = \frac1{\pi_i}$ for all states $i$, but there is no simpler way to compute the distribution of $T_i$.

Comment: @Math1000 if the distribution is stationary, why does it have a sub index ?

Comment: Here we would have $\pi = (\pi_1, \pi_2, \pi_3)$ where $\pi_i$ is the $i^{\mathrm{th}}$ component of $\pi$, corresponding to state $i$.

Comment: @Math1000 thanks, neat formula.

Comment: @Math1000 can I interest you in this question ? : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3501018/mathbbp-xt-0-3-1-frac13-mathbbp-xt-0-1